# Synchronous/sequential read/write to tty

Tags: tty, read

I am trying to communicate with a device at `/dev/ttyACM0`. I need to write one command, and await a response (ACK) before sending the next command.

I found the following [article](https://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2019/03/08/bash-send-data-to-serial-rs232-port-and-wait-for-response/) about how to achieve this, but I can't quite get it work for my use case. My guess is I lack understanding about the data I receive back and  that it isn't terminated by a new line.

I open one terminal and use cat:

```bsh
cat -v /dev/ttyACM0
```

I then print in another terminal:

```bsh
printf 'S0100000FF\x0d' > /dev/ttyACM0
```

The response I get in the terminal reading the tty is `^F`. Sending another command prints another on the same line, e.g. the line now displays `^F^F`, so I'm guessing it isn't terminated by a new line.

When using the read command (in a separate terminal) from the article linked above:

```bsh
(read -n 60 -t 20 RESP < /dev/ttyACM0; echo $RESP)&
[1] 21028
```

And then subsequent writes from the writing terminal does not trigger anything else to be displayed by the reading terminal.

I've also attempted a completely synchronous write by simply printing and then attempting to read the tty:

```bsh
printf 'S0100000FF\x0d' > /dev/ttyACM0
cat -v /dev/ttyACM0
# Blank, nothing in file
```

My problem boils down to three questions:

1. What does `^F` actually represent? I know `^M` is a carriage return,
   but I don't know what this type of character is called (e.g.
   characters prefixed by `^`).
2. I thought a tty was just a file, so how come the file is empty in my last example (printing and reading after each other)
3. How could I adapt the linked article to suit my purposes for a synchronous read/write  script?

Comment: Bash is an atrocious tool to use for serial programming. But if you're really into it, start with at reading the stty(1) and termios(3) manpages thoroughly. You should *at least* make the tty raw with `stty raw`. ^F is ASCII character 6 (ACK), but what it means depends on the protocol used by the device at the other end -- it may be that it acked your commands, ignored them or something else. And no, a tty is not "just a file".

Comment: It is not necessary to use bash, it was just handy to explore in. What would you recommend?

Comment: Any real programming language like perl, python, C would do. Even in bash, you could open the tty once with `exec {fd}<>/dev/ttyS0; stty raw <&"$fd"` and then read and write from that file descriptor (e.g. with `printf ... >&"$fd"`) instead of opening the terminal again and again. But bash doesn't support NUL bytes in its variables, and there's no way to read data as it comes, other than running `dd bs=1` in a loop ;-)

Comment: I see your point about not using bash. I'm familiar with python and it looks easy, I'll give it a try with that instead. Thank you

Comment: `expect` is a good tool for managing interactions.